# Calculate Number of Days

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to calculate the number of days from a field 'complaintdate' in my SQL database.
In this field store the date in which users register complaint.  I want to see the complaints pending 20 days and more from current date.

Is there is any other function or method to count number of days?
the code i used is

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("select complaintdate from complaintregister where compstatus='Attended & Open'", con);
rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if (rd.Read())
{
    string s = rd["complaintdate"].ToString();
}
```

i displayd 's' by

```
Response.Write(s);
```

and its diplayed in this format 4/5/2011 12:00:00 AM

`

Comment: what is the data type of the complaintdate ??? and what is ur database engine ?? mysql ??

Answer (score 3):

This will retrieve `totalDays` as the number of days between your `complaintDate` and today. Replace `GetDateFromDatabase()` with your means of retrieval:

```
DateTime complaintDate = GetDateFromDatabase();
int totalDays = (int)(DateTime.Now - complaintDate).TotalDays;
if (totalDays >= 20)
{
    // Perform your actions here. 20+ days have elapsed.
}
```

**EDIT:**

I have added the following code to use the code you provided in your edit. I am assuming variables `cmd`, `con`, and `rd` are declared elsewhere in your code.

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("select complaintdate from complaintregister where compstatus='Attended & Open' ", con);`
rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if (rd.Read())
{
    string s = rd["complaintdate"].ToString();
}

DateTime complaintDate;
try
{
    complaintDate = Convert.ToDateTime(s);
}
catch
{
    Response.Write("An error occurred while trying to convert the date!");
    return;
}

int totalDays = (int)(DateTime.Now - complaintDate).TotalDays;
if (totalDays >= 20)
{
    // Perform your actions here. 20+ days have elapsed.
}
```

Comment: its working...but resul is 155.450726453993 ... the date store in 4/5/2011 12:00:00 AM  format

Comment: I edited it to convert `totalDays` to an `int`, so it returns 155 without decimals. To render just the date, use: `complaintDate.ToString("m/d/yyyy")`

Answer (score 3):

From your question, I'm not sure if you want to do this comparison in the database or in code.

If you want to do the check in SQL Server, you can use the [DATEDIFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) function.

If you want to do the check in code, you can use `DateTime.Subtract`:

```
var complaintDate = new DateTime(2011, 9, 1);
var daysSinceComplaint = (int)DateTime.Now.Subtract(complaintDate).TotalDays;
Console.WriteLine(daysSinceComplaint);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution in SQL Server is to put in a calculated field in the table that displays how many days lapsed. Will show Null if CompliantDate is null

```
ALTER TABLE ComplianceTable ADD
DaysLapsed  AS datediff(dd,CompliantDate,getdate())
GO
```

Comment: Note my solution will get around date formatting etc as it will use SQL Server datetime frames and just return days lapsed in number so you just write in C# if (dayslapsed > 20) {DoSomething();}